# Set multiple PATH Variables in MacOS Big Sur (zsh)

Tags: macos, terminal, path, environment-variables, zsh

I want to add multiple Path Variables:

- Dart & Pub (Doesn't work)
- sdkman (works)
- homebrew and its installations (Doesn't work)
- Deno (Doesn't work)
- Cargo & Rust (works)
- Npm & NodeJS (Doesn't work, but worked without setting a path until i added cargo)

And that's my current .zshrc file:

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin"
export PATH="/Users/kloetzchengrafik/.deno/bin:$PATH"
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Cargo
PATH="/Users/kloetzchengrafik/.cargo/bin"
export PATH
```

Comment: The `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin"` and `PATH="/Users/kloetzchengrafik/.cargo/bin"` commands both replace (and effectively remove) all previous additions to `PATH`. To *add* entries to `PATH`, the value should either start with `$PATH:` or end with `:$PATH`. Also, you don't need to keep `export`ing `PATH, once is enough.

Comment: You can't have multiple `PATH` variables. It sounds like you want to use something like [`direnv`](https://direnv.net) to modify your environment based on your current working directory.

Comment: Unless you have a wildly atypical setup, all your shells already source `/etc/profile`, which takes care of creating and exporting `PATH`. You never need to "reexport" it, only change the value as necessary.

Comment: The lone `export PATH` is unnecessary. You have already exported it before. BTW, doing a `path+=(dir1 dir2)` is IMO simpler to write and read than `PATH=$PATH:dir1:dir2`, and the `+=` ensures that you don't overwrite existing path entries.